# Matching numbers between set strings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the ID number between two strings. The string looks like:

```
Ticket - Subject: opoipoipo |==Ticket ID: 7==|
```

The number could easily be 5 digits long

I've tried

```
(?<=is \|==Ticket ID:)(.*?)(?=\s*\)==|
```

And I don't think i'm far off, but i'm clearly doing something wrong. The idea being I just want it to say 7 and nothing more.

Comment: What's wrong with `\|==Ticket ID:\s*(\d+)==\|` and then you just get whatever is in capture group 1? The lookarounds add unnecessary complexity, not to mention they're not as widely supported by regex engines as a simpler expression.

Comment: @NullUserException have to escape '|'

Comment: @megawac Slipped my mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solution is definitely close. Consider the following minor change to your Regex...

```
(?<=\|\=\=Ticket ID:).*?(?=\s*\=\=\|)
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely close, I think the following should do it:

```
(?<=\|==Ticket ID:)(.*?)(?===\|)
```

The only part that isn't handled here is that you will get any whitespace with the value, but that should be easy to strip off.  The only reason I didn't include it in the regex is because many implementations do not support a variable length lookbehind, so putting `\s*` at the end of the lookbehind may not work.  If you know that there will always be a single space you could use the following:

```
(?<=\|==Ticket ID: )(.*?)(?===\|)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?<= \|==Ticket ID: )(.*?)(?=\s*==\|)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/E74dIhmYiH